# react-intl not changing placeholder value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

Am I doing something wrong here ?

I am calling `intl.formatMessage()` API (https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) as follows:

```
this.intl.formatMessage({id:'downloadRequest.success',values:{correlID:'test'}})
```

The string in my JSON file looks like:

```
 "downloadRequest.success": "Your request was successfully submitted. Your reference ID is: {correlID}"
```

However, when I view the page, the output is :

`Your request was successfully submitted. Your reference ID is: {correlID}`

i.e. `{correlID}` is not substituted for the `test` value provided to `formatMessage()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass values as the second argument.

```
this.intl.formatMessage({id:'downloadRequest.success'},{correlID:'test'})
```

Comment: Thanks very much !

Comment: @LittleCode Glad I could help.